# accordion-group - Items wont drop down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

My web guy made me a page with the accordion-group function on. The site is also made via twitter bootstrap.
It was all working fine and now its broke!

I am a complete beginner and saw people mentioning JSfiddle.

I copied the HTML into JSfiddle and it all works fine.
When on the webpage it does not. The items show but when you click on any item it just scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

I am sure this is a super easy fix as like i say it works perfectly in Jsfiddle just not in my browser. 
The link to JSfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/EFrZv/4/

```
<body>
        <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">Is Chamonixfirst Fully Legal to Perform Airport Transfers?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>Yes we are. At ChamonixFirst we have all the appropriate transport licences and the appropriate passenger carrying insurance to carry out pre booked transfers to resorts, airports etc.</p>
                        <p>We also have the appropriate Canton License's which allows us to enter Switzerland and pick up passengers from the airport and means our vehicles will not get impounded at the border at any time, which is becoming very common with companies who are not fully licensed and insured to the correct standards.</p>
                        <h2>Please see our particulars below:</h2>
                        <p><strong>Siret Number: 53499800000010</strong><br /> <strong>International transport license number: 2011/82/0002505</strong><br /> <strong>Code APE: 4939 B Transports de Voyageurs</strong><br /> <strong>Transport insurance : Alliance Chamonix</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">Flight time/check in time/take off time.....</a></div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>When booking a transfer from Geneva to resort please enter the arrival time of your flight when making the booking<br />When booking a transfer from resort to Geneva please enter the scheduled departure time of your flight and&#160;NOT&#160;the check in time<br />This way we can arrange schedules for the day for our drivers and make your transfer more efficient with minimum waiting at the airport</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">Must I book and pay for a seat for my baby ?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>Yes, the law states that everyone in the vehicle must occupy their own seat. When booking with babies and children please make sure you choose the correct type of baby/booster seat for your little ones during the booking process. Failure to book the appropriate seat for a child may result in your transfer being cancelled as it is illegal to carry minors without the correct seating</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">Do you provide baby/child seats?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>Yes, but you must choose the correct kind of seat required when booking. The seat will be in the vehicle when we come to collect you</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive">What is the Geneva Airport to Chamonix transfer time?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>The transfer time between Geneva Airport and Chamonix usually takes between 1hr 15 minutes to 1hr 30 minutes. This obviously depends on road/weather conditions though. Our drivers all have vast mountain driving experience and always drive accordingly for the weather conditions</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSix">Delayed/cancelled flights - whats happens then?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseSix" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>You should keep ChamonixFirst informed at all times about delayed and cancelled flights. If, because of a late flight you will not arrive at the time booked on your original transfer booking you must make ChamonixFirst aware as soon as possible by phoning the office or calling the drivers number which will have been texted to you the day before your transfer. Failure to do this may result in your transfer being cancelled or delayed</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSeven">Missed flight?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseSeven" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>In the event that you miss you flight you must call the Chamonixfirst office straight away. We will<br />reschedule your transfer for the next available vehicle leaving the airport but this may incur a wait during busy periods. Failure to contact ChamonixFirst may result in your ticket being void and in line with our terms and conditions we may cancel your transfer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseEight">What is the Geneva Airport to Chamonix Distance?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseEight" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>The Distance from Geneva Airport to Chamonix Mt Blanc is roughly 100 KM.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseNine">Geneva Chamonix transfers by mini bus?</a></div>
                <div id="collapseNine" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        <p>In our opinion using our mini bus service is the quickest and most efficient way to get to and from Geneva Airport from Chamonix. We are much cheaper than a private taxi booked at the airport and are far more flexible. Our friendly English drivers are full of local knowledge and all our vehicles are fully equipped for the alpine winter conditions</p>
                        <p>Please use the online&#160;booking form&#160;for your&#160;Geneva Chamonix transfer&#160;and all other transfers or alternatively you can call our booking line on +44 (0) 203 286 0618 or email us on&#160;<a href="mailto:info@chamonixfirst.com?subject=Info">info@chamonixfirst.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

A friend mentioned scripts but like i say i am a complete beginner and only understand HTML in a basic fashion.

Everything in the HTML section on Jfidle is everything on my page apart from the head tags. There is nothing else on there. I assume there should be something else but cant figure out what.

Please help!!
Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0):

your HTML is fine but make sure you are pointing to the right JavaScript Directory. 
try to replace your JQuery Script tag with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I will also recommend you check http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ for more hosted bootstrap libraries.

Comment: Hi Anthony, sorry i am really bad at this. Should i just paste      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 into the body? I have tried this but made no difference. I also pasted it into the head and still made no difference. The code above is all the HTML on the page apart from the HEAD tags. There must be something missing right? Sorry for the dumb questions

Comment: This is not a dumb question buddy.

Comment: look for your <script> / tag that contains the current jquery/ </script>. Remove that tag and Include the link above in your <body> preferably the last line</body>